# Pinescript - Get last element of one series and add it to another series

Tags: pine-script

I want to calculate daily ATR and plot previous day's close +/- ATR

I am able to calculate daily ATR, but when I add it to previous day's close, I am not getting a clear horizontal line.

```
//@version=4

study(title="Natr levels", shorttitle="Natr levels", overlay = true)

true_range(h, l, c) =>
    max(h - l, max(abs(h - c[1]), abs(l - c[1])))
    
res = input(title="Resolution", type=input.resolution, defval="D")
t =  syminfo.tickerid

daily_high = security(t, res, high) 
daily_low = security(t, res, low) 
daily_close = security(t, res, close) 

natrS = sma(true_range(daily_high, daily_low, daily_close), 22)

width = input(2, minval=1)

vPP = daily_close
// TODO: try to find array.get()
vR1 = daily_close + natrS // should only add last value
vS1 = daily_close - natrS

plot(vPP, color=color.yellow, title="PP", linewidth = width, style=plot.style_stepline)
plot(vS1, color=color.green, title="S1", linewidth = width, style=plot.style_stepline)
plot(vR1, color=color.red, title="R1", linewidth = width, style=plot.style_stepline)
```

How do I add a constant i.e. the last value of daily ATR to previous day's closing value?

screenshot - https://www.tradingview.com/x/YRbANLHc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't daily atr though. That will calculate the 22 period (as in 22 periods of the chart timeframe, not daily) average of the ATR. To obtain the atr correctly you need to use it in the context of a security call.

```
daily_close = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close)
daily_ATR = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", atr(22)) // <-- Correct
daily_TR = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", tr)

sma_atr = sma(daily_TR, 22) // <-- Incorrect

plot(daily_close)
plot(daily_close + daily_ATR, color = color.aqua) // <-- Correct
plot(daily_close + sma_atr, color = color.fuchsia) // <-- Incorrect
```